# KeyError while using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am slightly new to python still. What the end goal is to use the following code to search the list and print out each grb.name in the list. The thing is I am wanting to use user input and I am running into the problem that if the user enters a date that isn't in the list it needs to automatically correct it by adding one until it reaches the next grb_date and then execute the code. This goes for both the start_date and end_date.

```
for i, grb in enumerate(results): #prolem with multiple grb's in 1 day
    try:
        grb_date = (re.sub('[A-Z]','',grb.name))
        end_results = [i, grb_date]
        data[str(grb_date)] = i  # this is the important bit
#            print (end_results)
    except:    
        pass

#start_date = (input('What is the start date you want: '))  
#end_date = (input('What is the end date you want: '))   

while 1:
    start_date = input('Please choose a start date: ')
    end_date = input('Please choose an end date now: ')
    try: 
        while data[start_date] <= data[end_date]:
                print (results[data[start_date]].name)
                data[start_date] += 1

    except KeyError:
        while data[start_date] not in end_results:
            data[start_date] += 1
        x = data[data[start_date]]
        print ('Try using this date instead: %d'), x
```

This is what I currently have. I keep getting KeyError '111111' (or whatever the start_date was if it was wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the incorrect start_date does not exist as a key in dict *data*.

Change your last while loop to -

```
while data.get('start_date', None) not in end_results:
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a bit obvious

```
try: 
    while data[start_date] <= data[end_date]:
            print (results[data[start_date]].name)
            data[start_date] += 1
```

And ...

```
except KeyError:
    while data[start_date] not in end_results:
```

The same key, start_date, is occuring in your handling of the key error (causes by the same key). Although [EFAP](http://www.python-academy.com/courses/specialtopics/python_patterns.html) is great, do it properly.

You need to set start_date into data.